# Tooltip Flickers in IE When Absolutely Positioned

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, tooltip, css-position

My tooltip works like a drop down menu using CSS to popup. JavaScript assigns a class to parent to display an absolutely positioned child with display block/none on MouseOver and MouseOut events.

Test case: http://jsfiddle.net/6g4ds/6/

The problem is that it flickers in IE (8) when I move mouse inside the tooltip on different internal elements like IMG, P, A. This is not happening in the test case above, using almost identical code, but does happen on my page.

I tried to apply background colors and z-index'es with no luck. Flickering occurs anyway.

Suggest me which possible CSS properties can be triggered to play around with it for possible fix. I am getting out of ideas. There are many tooltips out there which probably solved this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using MouseEnter and MouseLeave solved my problem.